# 2 spark stream job with same consumer group id

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to experiment on consumer groups

Here is my code snippet

```
public final class App {

private static final int INTERVAL = 5000;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "xxx:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", true);
    kafkaParams.put("auto.commit.interval.ms","1000");
    kafkaParams.put("security.protocol","SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    kafkaParams.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka");
    kafkaParams.put("retries","3");
    kafkaParams.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"mygroup");
    kafkaParams.put("request.timeout.ms","210000");
    kafkaParams.put("session.timeout.ms","180000");
    kafkaParams.put("heartbeat.interval.ms","3000");
    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("venkat4");

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(INTERVAL));


    final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    ssc,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
            );

    stream.mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
                    return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                }
            }).print();


    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();


}
```

}

When I run two of this spark streaming job concurrently it fails with error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition venkat4-1
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:251)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.needOffsetReset(SubscriptionState.java:315)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(KafkaConsumer.java:1170)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:197)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:214)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
>       at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
>       at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)

Per this https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/apache-kafka-tutorial-1342/apache-kafka-consumer-group-example-19004.html creation of separate instance of kafka consumer with same group will create a rebalance of partitions. I believe the rebalance is not being tolerated by the consumer. How should I fix this

Below is the command used

SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=0.10 spark2-submit   --num-executors 2   --master yarn   --deploy-mode client   --files jaas.conf#jaas.conf,hive.keytab#hive.keytab   --driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./jaas.conf"   --class Streaming.App   --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./jaas.conf" --conf spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.enabled=false 1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: So far I tried configuring the below params and none of these worked

kafkaParams.put("request.timeout.ms","210000");
kafkaParams.put("session.timeout.ms","180000");
kafkaParams.put("heartbeat.interval.ms","3000");
kafkaParams.put("metadata.max.age.ms","1000");

spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.enabled=false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Per this https://www.wisdomjobs.com/e-university/apache-kafka-tutorial-1342/apache-kafka-consumer-group-example-19004.html creation of separate instance of kafka consumer with same group will create a rebalance of partitions. I believe the rebalance is not being tolerated by the consumer. How should I fix this

[image]

Now all the partitions are consumed by only one consumer. If data ingestion rate is high, consumer might be slow to consume data at the speed of ingestion.

[image]

Adding more consumer to the same consumergroup to consume data from a topic and increase the consumption rate. Spark streaming using this approach 1:1 parallelism between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions. Spark will handle it internally.

If you have more number number of consumers than topic partitions, it will be in idle state and resources are under-utilized. Always recommended the consumer should be less than or equal to partitions count.

> Kafka will re-balance, if more processes/threads are added. The ZooKeeper can be reconfigured by Kafka cluster, if any consumer or broker fails to send heartbeat to ZooKeeper.

***Kafka rebalance the partitions storage whenever any broker failure or adding new partition to the existing topic. This is kafka specific how to balance the data across partitions in the brokers.***

Spark streaming provides simple 1:1 parallelism between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions. If you are not providing any partition details using ConsumerStragies.Assign, consumes from all the partitions of the given topic.

> Kafka assigns the partitions of a topic to the consumer in a group, so
>   that each partition is consumed by exactly one consumer in the group.
>   Kafka guarantees that a message is only ever read by a single consumer
>   in the group.

**When you start the second spark streaming job, another consumer try to consume the same partition from the same consumer groupid. So it throws the error.**

```
val alertTopics = Array("testtopic")

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> sparkJobConfig.kafkaBrokers,
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> sparkJobConfig.kafkaConsumerGroup,
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest"
)

val streamContext = new StreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds(sparkJobConfig.streamBatchInterval.toLong))

val streamData = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamContext, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](alertTopics, kafkaParams))
```

If you want to consume partition specific spark job, use the following code.

```
val topicPartitionsList =  List(new TopicPartition("topic",1))

val alertReqStream1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamContext, PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Assign(topicPartitionsList, kafkaParams))
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#consumerstrategies

> Consumers can join a group by using the samegroup.id.

```
val topicPartitionsList =  List(new TopicPartition("topic",3), new TopicPartition("topic",4))

    val alertReqStream2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamContext, PreferConsistent, ConsumerStrategies.Assign(topicPartitionsList, kafkaParams))
```

Adding two more consumers is adding into same groupid.

Please read the Spark-Kafka integration guide.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: @venkat-sam could you please, acknowledge if this clarify the questions, it will useful for the other users.

Answer (score 2):

@Ravikumar Apologies for the delay.

My test was done like this

a. My topic has 3 partitions
b. The spark-streaming job was initiated with 2 executors -- which runs fine.
c. Later I decide to scale it up with another instance by running another spark-streaming job with 1 executor to match my 3rd partitions which fails.

Regarding your statement:
When you start the second spark streaming job, another consumer try to consume the same partition from the same consumer groupid. So it throws the error
Yes, this is exactly correct. But why its not tolerating is the question here.

Quoting the document you highlighted:

> Kafka assigns the partitions of a topic to the consumer in a group, so
>   that each partition is consumed by exactly one consumer in the group.
>   Kafka guarantees that a message is only ever read by a single consumer
>   in the group. Kafka rebalance the partitions storage whenever any
>   broker failure or adding new partition to the existing topic. This is
>   kafka specific how to balance the data across partitions in the
>   brokers. Kafka will re-balance, if more processes/threads are added.
>   The ZooKeeper can be reconfigured by Kafka cluster, if any consumer or
>   broker fails to send heartbeat to ZooKeeper.

This is what I was expecting for my spark-streaming job as well. I tried with normal-kafka clients which were able to tolerate rebalance.

Your point from the document "The cache is keyed by topicpartition and group.id, so use a separate group.id for each call to createDirectStream" clarified my question.

In-addition From the PR https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/21038 -- Following is metioned

> "Kafka partitions can be revoked when new consumers joined in the
>   consumer group to rebalance the partitions. But current Spark Kafka
>   connector code makes sure there's no partition revoking scenarios, so
>   trying to get latest offset from revoked partitions will throw
>   exceptions as [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22968) mentioned."

Good to close this thread. Thanks much for the response